# Backups for tlpkg during tlmgr update

Tags: texlive

Just now I decided to see what is the content of `/usr/local/texlive/2013/tlpkg/backups`.

There are 447 `tar.xz` files using around 500mb of disk space.

Is it safe to delete all those files? I use `tlmgr` once a week.

Comment: You have only 447 files in that directory? I have 694 such files... :-)

Comment: @Mico, here are my files: http://paste.ubuntu.com/7299263/

Comment: I have 688 of them. When you update a package, the last installed version is archived. Very useful if an update makes something go wrong, because you can restore the previous version.

Comment: @egreg, is it possible to restore it using `tlmgr`, right? Otherwise we should install it manually. Maybe you have more file because of some Win packages. I remember that I didn't choose to install that win part. Could you please, paste your list as I did, so I can compare both using Meld.

Comment: Yes, `tlmgr` allows to restore an archived version; you can also set the number of archived versions.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To see how many backups will be kept and where:

```
tlmgr option backupdir; tlmgr option autobackup
```

produces something like:

```
Directory for backups (backupdir): tlpkg/backups
Number of backups to keep (autobackup): 1
```

To change an option:

```
tlmgr option backupdir /path/to/alternate/directory
tlmgr option autobackup 96
```

To purge existing backups, you can use

```
tlmgr backup --clean=N --all
```

where `N` is the number to keep (defaults to the value of `autobackup` if unspecified). Note that this is untested as I don't wish to purge my own backups.

Alternatively, norbert has written a comment assuring us that it is perfectly safe to delete the files manually as `tlmgr` does not keep an independent record. Since norbert should know if anybody does, I take this to be as certain as anything involving computers can be. The built-in option is still slightly safer as it is more difficult to accidentally delete everything from the wrong directory. However, if you are confident you won't make this mistake, deleting manually should be equally effective.

However, I wouldn't delete them at all unless you need the disk space.

Comment: Deleting manully is no problem, `tlmgr` does not keep a record, and reads the backup directory if you ask for restores.

Comment: @norbert That's good to know. I had no idea whether it would or wouldn't cause issues so figured it was better to err on the side of caution in recommending anything.

Comment: the nice thing with tlmgr back --clean is that you can decide how many backups you want to keep. OTOH, if you want to keep only backups for one or two packages (crucial ones), then this is better done by hand.